# Printing selected data seperated by comma in python

Tags: python

I have my code like this:

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                 socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print "received message:", data
```

This is my output:

```
$$359138030323187,7001,2000/00/00,00:00:00,0.00000,0.00000,0.0,0,0,0,0,0.0,0,0.0,0,0,0,0.0,12.2,11,4,0.0##
```

I wanted only the 5th and 6th data columns to be displayed. Something like this:

```
The lat is 0.00000
The long is 0.00000
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) your data:

```
split_data = data.split(",")
print("The lat is {}".format(split_data[5]))
print("The long is {}".format(split_data[6]))
```